# Joint.js port connection position

Tags: svg, jointjs

I created custom elements with ports, but when connecting a link between them the link "arrow head" and port shape sometimes overlap with the "arrow head" inside the port. Another problem seems to be that if I move the elements around, it appears to disconnect at times.

Ultimately I would like the link to connect to a single point on the port and never "overlap" or "disconnect". Is there any way to prevent his behavior?

*Note that in the images the blue "arrow head" only shows on mouse over*.

[link overlapping port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K2hMm.png)

[link looks disconnected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FF6gU.png)

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: are you able to find any solution for this?